# AngularJS accessing DOM elements inside directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a more "angular" way of selecting DOM elements inside a directive template? For example, say you have this directive:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        template: '<div><ul><li ng-repeat="item in items"></ul></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var list = element.find("ul");
        }
    }
});
```

I used the jQuery style selector to get a hold of the DOM `<ul>` element rendered in my template. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In state, I don't think there is a better way to do that. But there is probably a better choice than select an element. What's your goal, exactly ?

Comment: Nothing in particular. This is just a common thing I keep running in to. I will need to access the DOM elements inside of a directive template for whatever reason, but using jQuery style selectors just seems wrong.

Comment: @Dustin like Blackhole mentioned, in 90% of the directives you dont need to access the DOM element through a selector - which is also the reason why Angular's JQueryLite supports very few and basic selectors. If you can let us know what you are attempting to achieve then someone would suggest a better way of doing it.

Comment: ganaraj, I don't know that I have anything specific right now. I have been needing these DOM elements for various reasons (e.g. applying CSS  styles to a list after ngRepeat has finished). I was just curious if anyone had an elegant solution to this need... creating a separate directive perhaps?

Comment: applying CSS styles to a list after ngRepeat has finished ? cant you use ng-class / ng-style with ng-repeat for this? The reason for questioning your questions is that , the premise for "the angular way of selecting DOM elements" itself seems wrong, since the angular way ( in most cases ) is not selecting DOM elements..

Comment: Ok good - this was the answer I was looking for. So basically, if I ever find myself needing to select DOM elements, there is probably a better way to accomplish the same thing using directives?

Comment: One use case is a nested list where you want to show and hide the children of the parent. Or, when you want to click one element and hide a 2nd when they're separate in the markup. `ng-show`?

Comment: i have same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114417/how-to-export-a-data-table-into-a-csv-file-in-angular

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could write a directive for this, which simply assigns the (jqLite) element to the scope using an attribute-given name.

Here is the directive:

```js
app.directive("ngScopeElement", function () {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {

    restrict: "A",

    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      return {
          pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
            scope[iAttrs.ngScopeElement] = iElement;
          }
        };
    }
  };

  return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

Usage:

```js
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        template: '<div><ul ng-scope-element="list"><li ng-repeat="item in items"></ul></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.list[0] // scope.list is the jqlite element, 
                          // scope.list[0] is the native dom element
        }
    }
});
```

Some remarks:

- Due to the [compile and link order for nested directives](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/bBgJ6Tb-mHo/PDSU76pNPtAJ) you can only access `scope.list` from `myDirective`s postLink-Function, which you are very likely using anyway
- `ngScopeElement` uses a preLink-function, so that directives nested within the element having `ng-scope-element` can already access `scope.list`
- not sure how this behaves performance-wise

Comment: I like this idea. Much cleaner... I wonder what the performance implications are.

Comment: This is such an elegant solution. Definitely going to implement this in my current project.

Comment: If `myDirective` declares its own scope, one needs to use `scope.$parent.list[0]` to get that element.

Comment: This will not work if you want to access elements inside an `ngIf` because they will be probably missing.

Comment: `Error: [$parse:isecdom] Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression: attachAttr($td, i)` this might happen

Answer (score 48):

I don't think there is a more "angular way" to select an element. See, for instance, the way they are achieving this goal in the last example of [this old documentation page](https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/docs/guide/directive):

```js
{
     template: '<div>' +
    '<div class="title">{{title}}</div>' +
    '<div class="body" ng-transclude></div>' +
    '</div>',

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // Title element
        var title = angular.element(element.children()[0]),
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is true but I think even in that example there is a more angular way of accomplishing the same thing. There is a `title.bind('click'...` that could just be an `ng-click` directive inside the template.

Comment: @DenisLins Long ago, it was the case. But the other answer is offering a perfectly correct solution, even if its heaviness should limit it to some very particular occasions.

Comment: I actually tried both answers, and they do work fine. But this one is way simpler, and it doesn't need a new directive just for that. I came here from googling basically this question's title, and I think this answer is better suited for most cases like mine. Anyway, I guess if they both work, there's no much harm in letting the other one be accepted.

Answer (score 5):

This answer comes a little bit late, but I just was in a similar need.

Observing the comments written by @ganaraj in the question, One use case I was in the need of is, passing a classname via a directive attribute to be added to a ng-repeat li tag in the template.

For example, use the directive like this:

```
<my-directive class2add="special-class" />
```

And get the following html:

```
<div>
    <ul>
       <li class="special-class">Item 1</li>
       <li class="special-class">Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The solution found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) applied with templateUrl, would be:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        template: function(element, attrs){
            return '<div><ul><li ng-repeat="item in items" class="'+attrs.class2add+'"></ul></div>';
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var list = element.find("ul");
        }
    }
});
```

Just tried it successfully with AngularJS 1.4.9.

Hope it helps.