# how to export a data table into a csv file in angular

Tags: angularjs, datatable

i have a data table in my angularjs app and i want to export it to a csv file .i searched alot in internet and i  found this directive ,but this only work when button is next to table .
need help to edit it...

```
app.directive('exportToCsv',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var el = element[0];
        element.bind('click', function(e){
            var table = e.target.nextElementSibling;//need to access to this element directly
            var csvString = '';
            for(var i=0; i<table.rows.length;i++){
                var rowData = table.rows[i].cells;
                for(var j=0; j<rowData.length;j++){
                    csvString = csvString + rowData[j].innerHTML + ",";
                }
                csvString = csvString.substring(0,csvString.length - 1);
                csvString = csvString + "\n";
            }
            csvString = csvString.substring(0, csvString.length - 1);
            var a = $('<a/>', {
                style:'display:none',
                href:'data:application/octet-stream;base64,'+btoa(csvString),
                download:'emailStatistics.csv'
            }).appendTo('body')
            a[0].click()
            a.remove();
        });
    }
}
});
```

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Comment: yeah ,i consider it as a secondary option but what i want to know is that how can i target  table in  my directive?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use UI Grid which is available at this link [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/312_exporting_data_complex)

The below code will allow you to export to either **PDF** or **CSV**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.exporter', 'ui.grid.moveColumns']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name' },
      { field: 'gender', cellFilter: 'mapGender', exporterPdfAlign: 'right' },
      { field: 'company', visible: false }
    ],
    exporterLinkLabel: 'get your csv here',
    exporterPdfDefaultStyle: {fontSize: 9},
    exporterPdfTableStyle: {margin: [30, 30, 30, 30]},
    exporterPdfTableHeaderStyle: {fontSize: 10, bold: true, italics: true, color: 'red'},
    exporterPdfOrientation: 'portrait',
    exporterPdfPageSize: 'LETTER',
    exporterPdfMaxGridWidth: 500,
    exporterHeaderFilter: function( displayName ) { 
      if( displayName === 'Name' ) { 
        return 'Person Name'; 
      } else { 
        return displayName;
      } 
    },
    exporterFieldCallback: function( grid, row, col, input ) {
      if( col.name == 'gender' ){
        switch( input ){
          case 1:
            return 'female';
            break;
          case 2:
            return 'male';
            break;
          default:
            return 'unknown';
            break;
        }
      } else {
        return input;
      }
    },
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){ 
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
  };

  $http.get('/data/100.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      data.forEach( function( row, index ) {
        if( row.gender === 'female' ){
          row.gender = 1;
        } else {
          row.gender = 2;
        }
      });
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });



  $scope.export = function(){
    if ($scope.export_format == 'csv') {
      var myElement = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location"));
      $scope.gridApi.exporter.csvExport( $scope.export_row_type, $scope.export_column_type, myElement );
    } else if ($scope.export_format == 'pdf') {
      $scope.gridApi.exporter.pdfExport( $scope.export_row_type, $scope.export_column_type );
    };
  };
}])

.filter('mapGender', function() {
  return function( input ) {
    switch( input ){
      case 1:
        return 'female';
        break;
      case 2:
        return 'male';
        break;
      default:
        return 'unknown';
        break;
    }
  };
});
```

HTML will look like

```
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-move-columns class="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

u can do this

```
var app = angular.module('tableCSV',[]);
    app.directive('exportToCsv',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var el = element[0];
            element.bind('click', function(e){
                var table = e.target.previousElementSibling;
                var csvString = '';
                for(var i=0; i<table.rows.length;i++){
                    var rowData = table.rows[i].cells;
                    for(var j=0; j<rowData.length;j++){
                        csvString = csvString + rowData[j].innerHTML + ",";
                    }
                    csvString = csvString.substring(0,csvString.length - 1);
                    csvString = csvString + "\n";
                }
                csvString = csvString.substring(0, csvString.length - 1);
                var a = $('<a/>', {
                    style:'display:none',
                    href:'data:application/octet-stream;base64,'+btoa(csvString),
                    download:'emailStatistics.csv'
                }).appendTo('body')
                a[0].click()
                a.remove();
            });
        }
    }
    });

    app.controller('sampleController',function($scope){
        $scope.message = "";
    });
```

u must change nextElementSibling to  previousElementSibling

Answer (score 3):

getElementById() for dynamic element access

**Directive**

```
app.directive('exportToCsv',function(){
 return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var el = element[0];
            element.bind('click', function (e) {
                var idName = e.target.name;
                var fileName = idName.split("--")[0];
                var tableId = idName.split("--")[1];
                var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
                var csvString = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                    var rowData = table.rows[i].cells;
                    for (var j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++) {
                        csvString = csvString + rowData[j].innerHTML + ",";
                    }
                    csvString = csvString.substring(0, csvString.length - 1);
                    csvString = csvString + "\n";
                }
                csvString = csvString.substring(0, csvString.length - 1);
                var a = $('<a/>', {
                    style: 'display:none',
                    href: 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + btoa(csvString),
                    download: fileName + '.csv'
                }).appendTo('body')
                a[0].click()
                a.remove();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="filename--divId" export-to-csv>Export posts</button>
```

Add a name element in the button tag where the first part is the file name & the second part is the id of the div to be selected.

Thank you.