# selecting angular element child item with jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a directive template that has div elments. And I want to select the inner element of a div. I mean I find any element in template.

```
<div class="body">
   <div class="container"></div>
</div>

angular.directive("myDir", function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope,element){
            element.find(".container");// does not return element
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Chk this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881453/angularjs-accessing-dom-elements-inside-directive-template

Comment: jqLite's `.find()` method has limitation of lookup elements with tagnames only.

Answer (score 0):

jqLite's `.find()` method has the limitation of lookup of elements with tag names only. So, the workaround is:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){ // first arg is for scope and second one is element.
    var _div = element.find("div");
    console.log(_div.hasClass('container'));
}
```